# Configure PyCharm to run appropriate variant of manage.py that is built within Docker container but doesn't exist in source code?

Tags: django, docker, pycharm

We have our program all dockerized and I'm now trying to get my pycharm to connect to it to debug something.  I've followed [these steps](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-debugging-pycharm/) but they are incomplete when it comes to how to define the Django application.

At this point I'm getting an error saying "python script path must be set" I believe this is because it can't find the `manage.py` Django script, which it wouldn't find.  Instead of having one `manage.py` script we have a dev, test, and prod script with different names.  I should be able to set this in the Django configuration in the 'manage script' field in theory.

Except our scripts are actually being built within the Docker environment, I don't have a `dev.py` script in my source code.  I could easily tell it the location of the script on the Docker container, but it won't let me type an arbitrary path, it wants me to select a file within my source code and there *is* no file in my source code at this point.

How can I point Django to a `dev.py` within my container?